# How do I change the colour of a button underline every time I hover over it to a different colour each time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a navbar that has an animated underline under buttons, I also want the colour of that same underline to change between 4 different colours but I cant figure out how. I tried to use a JavaScript script I found but it created a gradient instead of changing the colour of the whole underline.

```js
var colors = ["#74B087", "#DE7300", "#74B087"];

function animate() {};
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 6;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 22px 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: 9;
  transition: 300ms;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: #8F8F8F;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="centered_nav">
  <a href="#" title="Home">#</a>
  <a href="#" title="Services">#</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Fun-fact: you don't need any JS for CSS animations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS variable for the color, and set that variable in the mouseenter event (cycling through the array values).

```js
let colors = ["#74B087", "#DE7300", "#74B087"], idx = 0;
document.getElementById("centered_nav").addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
  this.style.setProperty('--link-color', colors[(idx = idx + 1) % colors.length]);
});
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 6;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  padding: 22px 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: 9;
  transition: 1s;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline var(--link-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="centered_nav">
  <a href="#" title="Home">Home</a>
  <a href="#" title="Services">Services</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It works great but it changes the text colour, I was hoping that you could add the underline animation with the colour as I haven't been able to get the animation and colours working at the same time, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again, another question, how would I increase the space between the underline and the text?

Comment: @Jamal Use text-decoration-offset: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset